# How can I call function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose that after click on the button - we send request. I have jquery plugin with structure like this:

```
(function($){

    $.myPlugin = {
        defaults: {}
    };

    $.fn.extend({
        /**
         * Initializes the plugin
         */
        myPlugin: function(settings)
        {
            return this.each(function() {

                settings = $.extend({}, $.myPlugin.defaults, settings);
                $.data(this, "myPlugin", settings);

                var self = this;

                $('#button', self).on('click', function () {
                    functionTwo.call(this);
                });
            });
        }
    });

    function functionOne()
    {
        alert(1);
    }

    function functionThree()
    {
        alert(3);
    }

    function functionTwo(self)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/some_url',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {

                // Here I need to call function depends on response.funcName.
                // Where funcName can be functionThree, functionOne, etc.
                // I try something like that: window[funcName], etc. But it was
                // not successfully.
            } 
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Here in functionTwo after ajax response I need to call function depends on response.funcName. Where response.funcName can be functionThree, functionOne, etc. I try something like that: windowfuncName, etc. But it was not successfully.

I don't understand where this functions (functionThree, functionOne, etc) are declared, in what scope? And how can I call it dynamically?

Comment: One way but a not secure one is `eval(response.funcName + '()');`

Comment: Define your functions in an object, e.g. `functions = {functionOne: function(){}}`, and, then use `functions[response.funcName]()`.

Comment: Yes about eval. I forgot to say that now I use this kind of solution, but, yes, it's not secured. Therefore I try to know better solution. :)

Comment: `window[funcName]` does not work because you do not declare function at window scope but in a lambda function. If you want to use it, declare `function functioOne`, etc. becore the `(function($){` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the functions in an object, so you can reference them with the bracket syntax:

```
(function($){
    var functions = {
        functionOne: function() {
            alert(1);
        },
        functionThree: function() {
            alert(3);
        },
        functionTwo: function(self) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/some_url',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    functions[response.funcName]();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $.myPlugin = {
        defaults: {}
    };

    $.fn.extend({
        /**
         * Initializes the plugin
         */
        myPlugin: function(settings)
        {
            return this.each(function() {

                settings = $.extend({}, $.myPlugin.defaults, settings);
                $.data(this, "myPlugin", settings);

                var self = this;

                $('#button', self).on('click', function () {
                    functions.functionTwo.call(this);
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```